# Выбор парсера командной строки

Tags: c#

Для beta тестирования своей либы по парсингу MPEG-TS пишу консольное приложение. Хочу организовать команды примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

транспортный поток можно подать 2-мя путями. через файл или через мультикаст.
-get общая для всех команда.
далее идёт название таблиц. у каждой таблицы свой набор команд.
-show_hex - общая команда для всех.
Решил не прыгать на грабли и взять готовое решение. Взял commandlineparser. Но выяснилось, что в терминологии commandlineparser я не могу использовать несколько Verb сразу.
Подскажите пожалуйста, какая библиотека позволит мне реализовать такое ветвление команд?

Comment: Так в команде только один verb (самое первое слово), если у вас не один verb, значит второй - это не verb.

Comment: В таком случае мне придётся делать описание одних и тех же команд для verb file и verb mcast.

Comment: Наследование и полиморфизм вас спасут. :)